# $(x^{2014}-x^{2004})\in \mathbb Z , \;(x^{2009}-x^{2004})\in \mathbb Z$ $\implies$ $x \in \mathbb Z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Let $x$ be a real number such that $(x^{2014}-x^{2004})$ and $(x^{2009}-x^{2004})$ are both integers. Then is $x$ also an integer ?

Comment: you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^{2014}-x^{2004} = a, x^{2009}-x^{2004} = b, a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{x^{2004}(x^{10}-1)}{x^{2004}(x^5-1)} = x^5+1 \in \mathbb{Q} \implies x^5 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Then $a-b = x^{2009}(x^5-1) \in \mathbb{Z} \implies x^{2009} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Then dividing gives $\frac{x^{4}x^{5 \cdot 401}}{x^5} \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $x^4 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Then $\frac{x^5}{x^4} = x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Let $x = \frac{p}q, \gcd(p,q) = 1$.

Then $b = \frac{p^{2009}-p^{2004}q^{5}}{q^{2009}}$ If $q \ne 1$ then take a prime $n$ of $q$ and take the numerator modulo $n$. You get $p \equiv 0 \pmod n$ which is a contradiction to $\gcd(p,q) = 1$.

Thus $q = 1$ and $x$ is an integer.

Comment: After concluding that $x$ is rational, you can stop because of the rational root theorem, since $x$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: **Counterexample** to the above argument: any nonreal root of $\,x^5-1.\ $ You do need to use the hypothesis that $\,x\,$ is *real* (else you may divide by zero in the second line).

Comment: Who are you replying to? Also, please be more clear.

Comment: @Sandeep The comment applies to your answer.